# Errors when adding GCM and crosswalk plugin on Cordova Android platform

Tags: cordova, build.gradle, crosswalk

I made Android platform using Cordova and added following code on build.gradle to use GCM.

```
∙apply plugin: ‘com.google.gms.google-services’

∙buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
∙ classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2’
∙ compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

It seems work well but when I excute gradle sync after adding crosswalk plug-in, some errors are showed up as follows.

```
∙Error:(194, 0) Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.
```

There is no file 'gradle.properties' on project list. So, as I create a file named 'gradle.properties', add another code as follows.

```
∙android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

But, I still have error that is not same as I mentioned before.

```
∙Error:exception during working with external system:
```

Does anyone have had same problems like I have? Please share your knowledge. I desperately need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your gradle.properties file under your project root path?

Comment: Yes. I created 'gradle.properties' file under project root path.